# Django Channels Server Configuration : Ubuntu. 404 on handshake

Tags: ubuntu, websocket, django-channels, redis-server, daphne

I'm trying to configure django channels to run on my ubuntu server(digital ocean).

I have redis-server running on `port 6379`.
Daphne is listening on endpoint `unix:/home/mysite/sockets/mysite.sock` with `HTTP/2 support enabled`(not sure that's required at this stage)
I also have one `./manage.py runworker` Listening.
My daphne run command was

```
daphne -u /home/mysite/sockets/mysite.sock project.asgi:channel_layer
```

My http requests come through(in the daphne log) as they did in my local environment e.g.

```
#local
127.0.0.1:62241 - - [09/Oct/2017:21:03:41] "GET /playground/channel-simple" 200 1826

#server (side note. not sure why port + host are eliminated here.?)
None - - [09/Oct/2017:21:53:51] "GET /playground/channel-simple" 200 1622
```

However, when I request a websocket url via js everything falls to pieces...

```
#local
127.0.0.1:62268 - - [09/Oct/2017:21:03:43] "WSCONNECTING /chat/private-room/" - -
127.0.0.1:62268 - - [09/Oct/2017:21:03:43] "WSCONNECT /chat/private-room/" - -

#server
None - - [09/Oct/2017:21:54:04] "GET /chat/private-room/" 404 86
```

It looks like it's treating the request as an http request rather than a websocket connection? This is also the js console log...

```
#server - js response to connection
WebSocket connection to 'ws://[MY-IP]/chat/private-room/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Can anyone advise as to where this 404 might be getting fired? Or any tips on debugging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've figured out the issue here and have now got it working on the server as expected. I had not completed the nginx config. Noob :).

The following articles were of great use.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

http://masnun.rocks/2016/11/02/deploying-django-channels-using-daphne/

Comment: Actually reading the docs worked for me. Specifically I had to add proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;